# How to efficiently query for a network (range)?

Tags: python, networking

I have a set of about 5000 network ranges with corresponding names (e.g. `192.168.0.0/24` -> `"Network Z"`) Many of the networks overlap, mask-wise = networks with a smaller mask may include networks with larger ones.

[image]

In the example above, `IP 1` should be matched with `NW D` (because it is the most specific, i.e. is the smallest one, has the largest mask), even though it would also match `NW B` and `NW A`.

I implemented this search using `netaddr` and having a sorted list of networks (ascending, by the `.size` attribute), which I iterate through looking for the first match. This solution works but is slow.

Is there a better solution?

**EDIT**: following up on the answer, a solution is to have the ranges as keys of a dict, [get a list all the supernets of the IP](http://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_01.html#supernets-and-subnets), iterate it in reverse order and check for existence of a key in the dict. This will give the smallest network containing the IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the masks.  To get a subnet, you AND the address with the mask. If you do that with multiple addresses and use the smallest mask, the results that are equal will all be part of the larger subnet.

For example:

- `10.11.12.13/32`
- `10.11.12.12/31`
- `10.11.12.12/30`
- `10.11.12.8/29`
- `10.11.12.0/28`
- `10.11.12.0/27`
- `10.11.12.0/26`
- `10.11.12.0/25`
- `10.11.12.0/24`

Mask each address with the smallest mask (`255.255.255.0`), and you will see that they are all in the range of `10.11.12.0/24`

Comment: This is an excellent idea, thanks! I will update the question with the code based on `netaddr`